# Current burst limits for Calrod heaters

Tags: current, pwm

I am considering a design for a Calrod heater controller that delivers power to the Calrod in bursts.  As an example, if I feed my 10 Ohm Calrod 100 VDC, it generates 1000 W.  If I assume a 1 second clock. I could also get 1000 W from the Calrod by feeding it a 500 ms burst of 141 V every second.  Or by feeding it a 100 ms burst of 316 V every second.  Clearly the Calrod must be able to take the voltage without shorting to the case. My question is this: maintaining 1000 W into the 10 Ohm Calrod, how can I determine the optimum clock frequency and how does this relate to the maximum voltage/current burst that can be applied to the Calrod's NiChrome heating element without it exploding?

Comment: If this information is available it would be from the heating element manufacturer.  Have you checked the specifications?

Comment: It might work it might not, depends on the Calrod's specifications. I always used 50 or 60 Hz for my heaters, easy to do with the AC line.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, Read-The-Fancy-Datasheet.

If you don't have the information you need available, be aware that mass products of any kind don't come with a significant safety margin. Safety margins are expensive.

If the heater is rated for 1000W at 100V AC, you can rely on it being safe up to 141V because a sine wave of 100V RMS has peak voltage of 141V.

Sure, it has some code-mandated safety margin above 141V, but this margin exists for a reason and is best left alone.

Of course, you can as well get a 230V rated heater (still pretty much a mass product) and be happy up to 315V.

You may as well discover that the same electrical insulation between the nichrome coil and the case is used in all products, no matter if they are 100V or 400V (3-phase voltage in 230V markets), but only the manufacturer can tell you for sure (look for case to coil voltage rating).

Regarding the PWM timing:

At the low-frequency limit, 50Hz or 60Hz (whatever is the mains frequency where you live) is obviously safe. Going lower requires estimating the heat capacity of the coil and deciding the acceptable temperature swing. Less than 1Hz is probably going to put unnecessary strain on the heater and it may crack prematurely. That's what you get if the thermostat in your oven switches too frequently.

The high-frequency limit is probably determined by the parasitic inductance, but if you keep it in the audible frequencies range (below 20kHz) it will be probably OK.